# Read/Callback multiple firebase values from query in Qt

Tags: qt, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, qt5

I'm trying to read all children of part of my database from one command, so I can update Firebase and it will automatically display in my app as the various titles.

the part of my database that I want to read is as follows:

- public

  - bigqueryobject

    - title1
    - title2
    - title3
    - title4

I am working in Qt and have tried different combinations using orderByKey, orderByChild and orderByValue with the following code:

```
firebaseDb.getValue("public/bigqueryobject",{
                        orderByKeys: true
                    }, function(success, key, value) {
                        if(success) {
                            console.debug("Read user value for key", key, "fromFBDB: ", value);
                            myArray.push(value); combobox.model = myArray
                        }
                    })
```

when doing the above my log states:

"Read user value for key bigqueryobject fromFBDB: [object Object]

Read Value [object Object] for keybigqueryobject"

yet no responses are displayed, what could be the issue here?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after previously trying to push the read value to an array to add to my combobox I was only getting one dropdown option with all read values in one row; simply removing the array worked perfectly, code below!

```
onFirebaseReady: {
    firebaseDb.getValue("locationsDepartments/locations", {
                            orderByValue: true
                        }, function(success, key, value) {
                             if(success) {
                                 combobox.model = value
                             } 
                       })
                  }
Quick2.ComboBox {
    id: combobox

    model: []

    delegate: Quick2.ItemDelegate {
        width: combobox.width
        height: combobox.height
        contentItem: AppText {
            text: modelData
        }
            highlighted: combobox.highlightedIndex == index
}
            contentItem: AppText {
               width: combobox.width - combobox.indicator.width - combobox2.spacing
               text: combobox.displayText
               wrapMode: Text.NoWrap
        }
}
```